# Can 'aplay' play sound from internet?

Tags: command-line, http, music-player

Can I use aplay to play sound from internet real time feedback such as:

```
aplay http://...
```

If possible, how to write the codes?

Comment: Don't think so, but you could use `mplayer` which does support HTTP.

Comment: [Related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375350/use-aplay-instead-of-mplayer), possibly duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Combine `aplay` with another command to download from URLs, such as `wget`, `curl`, or similar. Then pipe the output to `aplay`.

```
curl https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/wav/bachfugue.wav | aplay
```

Adjusting the various aplay options depending on the type of file being played, sample rate, etc.

Comment: Very clever and simple approach

Answer (score 2):

The question should really be:

> I have a system where I am not allowed to install things, but I want to play sound from the internet. `aplay` is installed. What can I do?

So instead of asking piecemeal for ways you thought how you may do it, just explain the situation.

There are basically two ways:

1) While you are not allowed to install packages in the system area, usually nobody prevents from installing stuff in your home-directory. So install or compile `mplayer` there.

2) First, find out **what format** the "sound from the internet" is using. There's streaming protocols, various ways to encode audio, etc. Not everything "on the internet" is the same. Then, find out what programs are available on this system to access the internet (wget, curl, netcat), find out if you have programs to decode the audio (libmp3 etc.), install what you need in your home-directory. Then you can imitate `mplayer` functionality in some way, by downloading the sound, converting it to raw or wav, and feeding it into `aplay`.

If this is easier than just compiling mplayer or not heavily depends on *what else* is available on your system.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  You are really right that I am not allowed to install things to the system.
Actually I want to do something like text to speech on a robot using 'google translate'.   The codes are:

#!/bin/bash
say() { local IFS=+;/usr/bin/mplayer -ao alsa -really-quiet -noconsolecontrols "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&client=tw-ob&q=$*&tl=en"; }
say $*

So I need to install mplayer but I failed to do so.  I will try your suggested methods using curl or wget and hope to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

As this option is [not documented](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/aplay1.html), NO, it does not support HTTP.

If you need HTTP, you may try [`mplayer`](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html).

Comment: I can't use mplayer since it was not allowed to be installed to the system.

Comment: @user239158 Then I see no other way for you;